# plist utility to convert info.plist in iphone app

Tags: iphone, command-line, build, plist

I try to build an iPhone app with command line.

I have a problem on Info.plist file.

XCode converts a XML file **MyApp-Info.plist** to a binary file **Info.plist**, like this :

```
builtin-infoPlistUtility MyApp-Info.plist -genpkginfo <path>/MyApp.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphoneos -resourcerulesfile <path>/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist -o <path>/MyApp.app/Info.plist
```

Today, I compile **Info.plist** with XCode and then I can sign MyApp.app with codesign successfully.

I try to compile **Info.plist** with plutil tool, like this :

```
plutil -convert binary1 <path>/MyApp.app/Info.plist
```

It works, but then codesign failed with error :

```
object file format invalid or unsuitable
```

I think I need other options for **plutil** utility but I don't know which ones.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im quite sure that the `Info.plist` file does not need to be in binary format to work. Does work if you just leave it as standard XML file?

I have seen this error message when the `CFBundleResourceSpecification` key was missing, should probably have the value `ResourceRules.plist`. It also seams to happen if the `CFBundleExecutable` key is missing.

A good way to see which keys that are used in a resulting app bundle is to do this:

1. Create a new fresh iOS app in Xcode
2. Configure minimum version, platform, orientations etc.
3. Build the app
4. Expand the "Product" group in the project tree and choose "Show in finder" on the app
5. Choose "Show Package Contents" on the app bundle
6. Open the `Info.plist` file and inspect it

Use `plutil` if you want to convert to resulting binary plist to XML format.

Comment: That's it ! I thought I had to have a binary Info.plist like XCode does, because when I signed .app I had an error. But including CFBundleResourceSpecification key as you mentionned, it works ! Great ! Thank you !

Comment: But I have another question I did not found : I would like to specify the "IOS target deplyment" as I can do with XCode. I tried "MinimumOSVersion" key in Info.plist, but it's deprecated by Apple and codesign fails with this key. Any help ?

Comment: `LSMinimumSystemVersion` seams to be the new key. I updated my answer with a more generic way of figuring out keys used on final app bundles.